# Return type in asynchronous function using mongoose produces error

Tags: typescript, mongoose, promise, async-await, return-type

I am getting an error while trying to compile the following code:

```
public getCompanies(): Array<ICompany>{
    Company.find({}, (err, data)=>{
        if (err) console.log(err);
        let companyArray = new Array();
        for (let company of data){
            companyArray.push(company);
        }
        return companyArray;
    });
}
```

There is an error with the return type of the function: *error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.*

Got the same error using then/catch functions.

Is there a way to make this work without converting the return type to *any*?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is right about your function not actually returning any value.

The problem is that `Company.find` takes a callback which is executed at a later date when the requested query competes.  So everything you write after `(err, data)=>{` will get not get executed when you call `getCompanies`, and the `return` you have is not a return from `getCompanies`, but rather a return from an anonymous function that get executed later.

You can either use a similar approach (passing in a callback) to be notified of when the query completes:

```
class foo {
    public getCompanies(onCompleted: (data: ICompany[])=> void): void{
        Company.find({}, (err, data)=>{
            if (err) console.log(err);
            let companyArray = new Array();
            for (let company of data){
                companyArray.push(company);
            }
            onCompleted(companyArray);
        });
    }

    public usage(){
        this.getCompanies(data=> 
        {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }
}
```

Or you can just return the `DocumentQuery` that `find` returns and use `then` or `async/await` to get the result:

```
class foo {
    public getCompanies() {
        return Company.find({}, (err, data)=>{
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            let companyArray = new Array();
            for (let company of data){
                companyArray.push(company);
            }
        });
    }
    public async usageAsync(){
        let data = await this.getCompanies();
        console.log(data);
    }

    public usage(){
        this.getCompanies()
            .then (data=> 
            {
                console.log(data);
            })
    }
}
```